# Ignore IPv6 RA on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, ipv6

Ubuntu server running on a network that has IPv6 with RA, but traffic needs to be sent out on a different IPv6 address to a different router.

It is not possible to segregate the traffic, so both need to be on the same L2 domain.

A static IPv6 address, subnet and gateway has been set in /etc/network/interfaces

I have tried the following lines in sysctl.conf individually and together

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.autoconf = 0
net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_ra = 0
net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_ra_defrtr = 0
net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_ra_rtr_pref = 0
net.ipv6.conf.default.autoconf = 0
net.ipv6.conf.default.accept_ra = 0
```

using `ip -6 route show` shows a default route using the RA, not the gateway set in /etc/network/interfaces.

Is there something I'm missing ?